# Gulp watch task was working fine, but is now generating an error when I try to start it

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm working on a course project using gulp.  Gulp has been working fine for weeks, but today I sat down at my computer to continue the course and am getting an error when I try and start my gulp watch task.  Again, this has been working fine for weeks prior to today.

When I attempt to run gulp watch I get the following error:

```
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._basevalues'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/rockypruitt/Google Drive/Web Design and 
Development/Learning to Code/Udemy-Git a web developer job - Brad   
Schiff/Sites/travel-site/node_modules/lodash.template/index.js:11:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try updating dependencies from your packages.json file?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  No, I didn't update anything in my package.json file.  I did check to see what version of gulp and gulp watch my package.json file shows as dependencies and they both match with the latest available versions.  I also checked to confirm that the version of gulp I show as installed locally matches the dependency.   

Is there something else I should check?  Or update?

Comment: If you have all the latest and greatest, try fresh npm install that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Rocky you should try with Remove node_modules folder and run npm install again.

Comment: Thank you for the response Maya.  I will give that a try.